# MagicalRecord documentation into Xcode

Tags: xcode, magicalrecord

I'm wondering how to add documentation/ api reference for MagicalRecord Library into Xcode?
Is there a feed or build way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link to MagicalRecord [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MagicalRecord/2.1/index.html)
And [here](http://cocoadocs.org) you can find documentation for many libraries

**Installation guide:**
1) go to This [link](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MagicalRecord/2.1/index.html)
2) on the right upper corner click on Xcode icon and copy url
3) open Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads (documentation tab)
4) click + button, enter url (from step 2), add
5) restart Xcode and that's it.

MagicalRecord don't have much documentation right now, hope they will add in future

Answer (score 0):

This might be best filed as a bug in the issue tracker on the [github project page](http://github.com/magicalpanda/magicalrecord/issues).

Comment: Yeah, we'll look into it. You're the first one to ask btw, so it's not terribly high on the priority list :(